# In Dawn of Defiance: The Traitor's Gambit, when do the PCs level?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

I've been playing no-XP Pathfinder for quite some time and I've gotten out of touch with the XP grind. As an introduction to Star Wars Saga Edition, we're playing through the free campaign Dawn of Defiance (or at least the first part of it).

In the first adventure, The Traitor's Gambit, at what points should the PCs level? Assume they do not bypass any encounters nor gain any extra XP above and beyond what is specified in the module write-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I attempted to make a chart in excel, with one column assuming they're getting awarded for all the bonus encounters, and one for if they do none of them. Then I did columns that divide each total by four. If my math is right, they level after either Frozen Goods or Felucian Hospitality, depending if they got extra XP for befriending Switch, and again after Detention Block in either case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **XP points** for the PCs depends on the **LVL** of the PCs and the **CL** of the encounter. In The Traitor's Gambit the guide itself tells you when to give the XP and how much.

If you need help to estimate the XP you can check on the Core Rulebook page 248.
If you want help to measure encounter difficulty just go back to page 247.

Here on [The Saga Continues](http://thesagacontinues.createaforum.com/general-discussion/saga-index/) they created a MUST HAVE SAGA Index where, in addiction of other things, you can find a CL Calculator.

If you want some clarification about the exact time the PCs levels up during the missions, moving from LVL 1 to LVL 3, I can only talk from my little experience as GM and by the istructions provided at page 2 of the PDF:

> This first adventure will get the heroes together and launch them down
>   a path to making a big difference in the galaxy, and the heroes should
>   advance to 3rd level by the conclusion of the adventure.

So, presuming they start with LVL 1 PCs, they should advance to LVL 3 at least by the end of the last part of The Traitor's Gambit: **Imperial Prison Facility**