# How do I read the challenge level in Dawn of Defiance's encounters?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

When trying to solve [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/in-dawn-of-defiance-the-traitors-gambit-when-do-the-pcs-level), I stumbled over the format of the encounters defined. The first encounter, Promenade Shootout, says "Challenge Level 1", so I awarded my players 200 xp to split. One of them pointed out that they defeated four guys, each of which has "Challenge Level 1" next to his stat block. Should they have gotten 800xp for defeating four level 1 challenges, or 200 xp for defeating a level 1 encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be per dude, not per encounter, which marks a change from DnD 3.5 that I'm used to. Consider the math for XP per encounter level:

[image]

Vs per enemy:
[image]

As you can see, they only end up level 3 at the end if you calculate it per enemy. I wish it didn't say the challenge level so prominently in the adventure to confuse me :(

Comment: Seems correct.  Saga is kind of a weird bastard stepchild of 3.5e and 4e in a lot of ways, this might be a legacy of that.